# Console crashing after scanf command

Tags: c, printf, scanf

Here is the code, he is causing the crashes but he is pretty simple:

```
int main() {

char* nome;
printf("Digite seu nome:  ");
scanf("%s",&nome);
printf("O nome digitado foi %s \n",nome);

return 0; }
```

0 warning, but the console crash after I type a simple word.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&nome);`..please read a C book, again.

Comment: You may want to allocate some space for that `nome` variable

Comment: [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @SouravGhosh You copy pasted my line of code?

Answer (score 1):

`nome` is an uninitialized pointer, and you're trying to store a string there. But there is no "there", so you get undefined behavior.

Try:

```
char nome[128];
```

that will give you some space. This is still dangerous (no limit to how much `scanf()` will store), but should take you one step further.

Comment: also `scanf("%s",&nome);` should be `scanf("%s",nome);` (even if it works with a char array)

Comment: I bought a beginner book and he said the other way to me, people are fast to say "read a book" even if you're trying, for example, @SouravGhosh is the least helpful user in this site. I will try to buy another book.